# Declare custom Types in Swift and Java-Kotlin

Tags: swift

I'm beginner in programming. I'm learning Swift and Java-Kotlin to develop apps. 
Also I'm student in IT Engineering.

I have learnt in C Language modularity that means to have a library where declare the types and the actions and functions and I call these actions, functions and types in the main file declaring the files in the header.

I was trying to do something similar in Swift and Kotlin, to have a file where declare my custom types and call them in the different views-classes.

In Swift I know that is not necessary to import the file where the types are.

For instance, I have declared the following types in Swift

```
struct tUser {

    var userId: Int
    var name: String
    var birthday: tDate
    var location: String
    var province: String
    var email: String
    var userPassword: String
    var picture: Image
    var favorites: tFavorite
}

struct tDate {

    var day: Int
    var month: Int
    var year: Int
}

struct tFavorite {

    var identifyer: Int
}

If I would initialize the types in C I would do

tUser newUser;

newUser.userId = 001;
newUser.name = "John"
```

I'm trying to do the same in Swift and Kotlin but, in Swift I get error "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" also in Kotlin I have errors.

Perhaps the answer is that there is no sense to do this in a Object Oriented Language,

Can someone help me in this matter?

Thanks,

Comment: Can I suggest trying only one of Swift and Kotlin at the same time? The snippets you have are not valid Kotlin (they might be valid swift).
When you say "also in Kotlin I have errors", please provide the full code, and at what error message you get and exactly where.

Comment: I removed the other language tags since this specific question is about swift and maybe you should focus your learning at one language at a time and specially to learn basic object oriented programming concepts.

Comment: The example types are in Swift, sorry, I didn't want to post a big message and I decided don't add the Kotlin types. Next season I will choose Object Oriented subject for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see a new person diving into Swift, welcome!

You can do what you are trying to do in Swift, but you have to be in a scope where it's allowed (e.g. **a class or struct**).

If you create a new **Playground** instead of an XCode project, you should be able to do it like you do in C.

If you want to use a project instead, the **"New Project"** template in XCode should give you a **"ViewController.swift"** file you can work on.

Just for starters, create a new **"Example.swift"** file in your project and paste your struct definitions there. After that, go back to your **ViewController.swift** file and see the function ***viewDidLoad***. Inside there, try to initialize your objects like you did.

That should solve the ***scope*** problem. As for the initialization problem, you can't exactly create your objects like C without providing default values for your properties:

```
struct tUser {
    var userId: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var birthday: tDate
    var location: String = ""
    var province: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var userPassword: String = ""
    var picture: Image
    var favorites: tFavorite
}
```

I'll let you figure out how to do the same for your custom `tDate` and `tFavorite` structs. After you provide them, you should be able to initialize an object with:

`var user = tUser()`

Another option is to define your properties as `Optional` like: `var name: String?`. `Optional` is a separate discussion topic on its own.

I suggest reading [the official Swift e-book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) for a basic understanding of initialization and overall the language when starting out. It's documented quite well in my humble opinion.

Hope it helps you out, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will follow your instructions,

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do exactly what you want in Kotlin (I don't know about Swift), by putting each type into a class and putting your code in a top-level function.  But that's not taking advantage of the benefits of objects.

Generally speaking, in an object-oriented language, you bundle the data (state) *with* the operations you can perform on that data (behaviour); together, that forms a class.

You don't show any operations here, but I'm sure you know what you're planning to do with your User, Date, and Favorite types.  For example, suppose one of the things you'll want to do with your Date is see whether today is an anniversary: you'd have a method (class function) for that.  Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
class Date(val day: Int, val month: Int, val year: Int) {

    fun isAnniversaryToday(): Boolean {
        // TODO Code here
    }
}
```

Then you could create your Date with `val myDate = Date(2, 6, 2000)`, and check whether it's a birthday with `myDate.isAnniversaryToday()`.

That's a bad example, though, because writing your own date classes is a really bad idea — it's so easy to get wrong, or hit problems with timezones or leap seconds or summer time or calendar differences, and most languages have pretty good date handling in their standard library.  So in the case of Java and Kotlin/JVM, you should use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes instead.  And similarly for images, lists, and a host of other types.  Generally speaking, anything that's not specific to your app is likely to have been done before, so (unless you're writing for practice) you should avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible!

So the main difference from what you've learned in C is the mind-set: in a procedural language like C a program is a collection of functions and data structures, while in an OO language a program is a collection of interrelated classes, each with some data and/or behaviour.  Each method is tied tightly to its class, easy to find and in the class's namespace, and it gets privileged access to the class's state (which you can restrict or hide from everything else).  That can take a bit of getting used to, but it turns out to be a really powerful technique for writing large systems safely.

None of this is specific to a particular language.  As I said, I don't know Swift, but I'd expect the principles work pretty much the same as in Kotlin, or C++, or many other modern languages.  So you might want to read a little about OO design, as well as any language tutorials.

(This site isn't the place for advice about which technologies to choose, but I can say that I love Kotlin: it's safer, cleaner, and more concise and expressive than any other language I've tried, and it's a real pleasure to use.  Now it's the official Android language, people associate it with that, but it's a perfectly good general-purpose language — we do all our back-end development in it, and I've written desktop apps with it.  All the docs are [online](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/), and there are some [good books](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) too.)

And one point that *is* specific to Kotlin: if your structure really *is* just a data holder and has no behaviour, then it's often best to make it a `data class`, e.g.:

```
data class Date(var day: Int, var month: Int, var year: Int)
```

The compiler will then generate implementations for many standard methods ([`equals()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/equals.html), [`hashCode()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html), [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/to-string.html), copy-constructors, &c) which will give it value semantics: for example, two objects with the same state will be treated as equal, which isn't the default for most classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is really appreciated. I will try a tutorial to general Object Oriented Language and of course next year I will choose Oriented Object subject. I'll follow your recomendatiosn